# Exception in Application start: method java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, maven, javafx

I'm new to JavaFX. So I'm trying to get my application up and running and I'm using Maven package.

So these are my issues:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:465)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:364)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1071)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:901)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:196)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3324)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3287)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3255)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3227)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3203)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3196)
    at com.example.javafxdemo/com.example.javafxdemo.Main.start(Main.java:12)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:847)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:484)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:457)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:456)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application com.example.javafxdemo.Main
```

This is the the image of my files and folders:

https://ibb.co/DL0PnpP

And main file:

```
package com.example.javafxdemo;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Home.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("KeepToo SMSys");
        primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image("/icons/icon.png"));
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    //you can download the glyph browser - link provided.
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Any ideas how to handle that?

Comment: You appear to be  misinterpreting the stack trace. The InvocationTargetException isn't what matters. Instead, it is the null pointer exception that matters. Is your file path correct? Are you sure?

Comment: Where exactly should I move my file? And which file path exactly?

Comment: Please check the answers in the duplicate. Resources use the class path for relative path

Comment: Still didn't find the solution in the duplicate, can you try to explain how to use that in my case?

Comment: There are not so much solutions for Maven project, I'm using a Maven project. Can you post an answer if you have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: Nothing here looks wrong to me. At least in the build under `target/classes`, `Main.class` is in the same package as `Home.fxml`, so `getClass().getResource(“Home.fxml”)` should work fine. Are you running this from the file system (as opposed to from a jar file)?